# cv::imshow in opencv is only displaying parts of a composite image, but displaying the parts separately works. Why?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, highgui

#### Objective and problem

I'm trying to process a video file on the fly using OpenCV 3.4.1 by grabbing each frame, converting to grayscale, then doing Canny edge detection on it. In order to display the images (on the fly as well), I created a Mat class with 3 additional headers that is three times as wide as the original frame. The 3 extra headers represent the images I would like to display in the composite, and are positioned to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd horizontal segment of the composite.

After image processing however, the display of the composite image is not as expected: [the first segment (where the original frame should be) is completely black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkCck.png), while the other segments (of processed images) are displayed fine. If, on the other hand, I [display the ROIs one by one in separate windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlkJ.png), all the images look fine.

#### These are the things I tried to overcome this issue:

1. use .copyTo to actually copy the data into the appropriate image segments. The result was the same.
2. I put the Canny image to the compOrigPart ROI, and it did display in the first segment, so it is not a problem with the definition of the ROIs.
3. - Define the composite as three channel image
   - In the loop convert it to grayscale
   - put processed images into it
   - convert back to BGR
   - put the original in.

This time around the whole composite was black, nothing showed.

4. As per gameon67's suggestion, I tried to create a namedWindow as well, but that doesn't help either.

#### Code:

```
int main() {

    cv::VideoCapture vid("./Vid.avi");
    if (!vid.isOpened()) return -1;

    int frameWidth = vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int frameHeight = vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    int frameFormat = vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT);

    cv::Scalar fontColor(250, 250, 250);
    cv::Point textPos(20, 20);

    cv::Mat frame;

    cv::Mat compositeFrame(frameHeight, frameWidth*3, frameFormat);
    cv::Mat compOrigPart(compositeFrame, cv::Range(0, frameHeight), cv::Range(0, frameWidth));
    cv::Mat compBwPart(compositeFrame, cv::Range(0, frameHeight), cv::Range(frameWidth, frameWidth*2));
    cv::Mat compEdgePart(compositeFrame, cv::Range(0, frameHeight), cv::Range(frameWidth*2, frameWidth*3));


    while (vid.read(frame)) {
        if (frame.empty()) break;

        cv::cvtColor(frame, compBwPart, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::Canny(compBwPart, compEdgePart, 100, 150);
        compOrigPart = frame;

        cv::putText(compOrigPart, "Original", textPos, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, fontColor);
        cv::putText(compBwPart, "GrayScale", textPos, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, fontColor);
        cv::putText(compEdgePart, "Canny edge detection", textPos, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, fontColor);

        cv::imshow("Composite of Original, BW and Canny frames", compositeFrame);
        cv::imshow("Original", compOrigPart);
        cv::imshow("BW", compBwPart);
        cv::imshow("Canny", compEdgePart);
        cv::waitKey(33);
    }
}
```

#### Questions

- Why can't I display the entirety of the composite image in a single window, while displaying them separately is OK?
- What is the difference between these displays? The data is obviously there, as evidenced by the separate windows.
- Why only the original frame is misbehaving?

Comment: Have you tried show the combined images using namedWindow( "Composite of Original, BW and Canny frames", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); ?

Comment: `compOrigPart = frame` is a simple assignment of the `Mat` (which is kind of like a shared pointer). What you want is to copy the contents of `frame` to the ROI represented by `compOrigPart `...

Comment: @gameon67 creating a namedWindow doesn't help a bit unfortunately, but thanks...

Comment: @DanMašek As I already described in point 1 of "These are the things I tried to overcome this issue: " section of the post, copying the contents of `frame` to the ROI doesn't help.

Comment: I can only comment the code I see. The problem is likely a combination of multiple factors. Not copying is certainly not going to help, due to the reasons I already explained. It's hard to tell what data type `compositeFrame` uses, but I guess it's BGR, since you later convert frame from BGR to grayscale. However, you then assign the result of conversion to one of the ROIs.-- if the data types don't match a reallocation is done and it's no longer a ROI (but a new, independent, array).

Answer (score 1):

Your compBwPart and compEdgePart are grayscale images so the Mat type is CV8UC1 - single channel and therefore your compositeFrame is in grayscale too. If you want to combine these two images with a color image you have to convert it to BGR first and then fill the compOrigPart.

```
while (vid.read(frame)) {
  if (frame.empty()) break;

  cv::cvtColor(frame, compBwPart, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  cv::Canny(compBwPart, compEdgePart, 100, 150);
  cv::cvtColor(compositeFrame, compositeFrame, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
  frame.copyTo(compositeFrame(cv::Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight)));

  cv::putText(compOrigPart, "Original", textPos, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, fontColor); //the rest  of your code
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it as well (see: point 3 in "These are the things I tried to overcome this issue"). Your solution won't even run properly (throws exception), as the composite image has three channels (see: `int frameFormat = vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT))` and `cv::Mat compositeFrame(frameHeight, frameWidth*3, frameFormat`). By trying to convert it from grayscale (which it is not), and exception is thrown.
I described in point 3 a safer way to do what you suggest, but that didn't help either.

Comment: @pusrob "as the composite image has three channels" -- no, that's just your assumption. All that code tells us that it has the type set to the value returned by `vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT))`. The problem is... that property is not always reliable. For example, I've just had it return 0 (meaning `CV_8UC1`) for a color video, and then give me 3 channel frames.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of several issues.

The first problem is that you set the type of `compositeFrame` to the value returned by `vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT)`. Unfortunately that property doesn't seem entirely reliable -- I've just had it return 0 (meaning `CV_8UC1`) after opening a color video, and then getting 3 channel (`CV_8UC3`) frames. Since you want to have the `compositeFrame` the same type as the input frame, this won't work.

To work around it, instead of using those properties, I'd lazy initialize `compositeFrame` and the 3 ROIs after receiving the first frame (based on it's dimensions and type).

---

The next set of problems lies in those two statements:

```
cv::cvtColor(frame, compBwPart, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Canny(compBwPart, compEdgePart, 100, 150);
```

In this case assumption is made that `frame` is BGR (since you're trying to convert), meaning `compositeFrame` and its ROIs are also BGR. Unfortunately, in both cases you're writing a grayscale image into the ROI. This will cause a reallocation, and the target `Mat` will cease to be a ROI.

To correct this, use temporary `Mat`s for the grayscale data, and use `cvtColor` to turn it back to BGR to write into the ROIs.

---

Similar problem lies in the following statement:

```
compOrigPart = frame;
```

That's a shallow copy, meaning it will just make `compOrigPart` another reference to `frame` (and therefore it will cease to be a ROI of `compositeFrame`).

What you need is a deep copy, using `copyTo` (note that the data types still need to match, but that was fixed earlier).

---

Finally, even though you try to be flexible regarding the type of the input video (judging by the `vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT)`), the rest of the code really assumes that the input is 3 channel, and will break if it isn't.

At the least, there should be some assertion to cover this expectation.

---

Putting this all together:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture vid("./Vid.avi");
    if (!vid.isOpened()) return -1;

    cv::Scalar fontColor(250, 250, 250);
    cv::Point textPos(20, 20);

    cv::Mat frame, frame_gray, edges_gray;
    cv::Mat compositeFrame;
    cv::Mat compOrigPart, compBwPart, compEdgePart; // ROIs

    while (vid.read(frame)) {
        if (frame.empty()) break;

        if (compositeFrame.empty()) {
            // The rest of code assumes video to be BGR (i.e. 3 channel)
            CV_Assert(frame.type() == CV_8UC3);
            // Lazy initialize once we have the first frame
            compositeFrame = cv::Mat(frame.rows, frame.cols * 3, frame.type());
            compOrigPart = compositeFrame(cv::Range::all(), cv::Range(0, frame.cols));
            compBwPart = compositeFrame(cv::Range::all(), cv::Range(frame.cols, frame.cols * 2));
            compEdgePart = compositeFrame(cv::Range::all(), cv::Range(frame.cols * 2, frame.cols * 3));
        }

        cv::cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::Canny(frame_gray, edges_gray, 100, 150);

        // Deep copy data to the ROI
        frame.copyTo(compOrigPart);
        // The ROI is BGR, so we need to convert back
        cv::cvtColor(frame_gray, compBwPart, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
        cv::cvtColor(edges_gray, compEdgePart, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

        cv::putText(compOrigPart, "Original", textPos, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, fontColor);
        cv::putText(compBwPart, "GrayScale", textPos, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, fontColor);
        cv::putText(compEdgePart, "Canny edge detection", textPos, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, fontColor);

        cv::imshow("Composite of Original, BW and Canny frames", compositeFrame);
        cv::imshow("Original", compOrigPart);
        cv::imshow("BW", compBwPart);
        cv::imshow("Canny", compEdgePart);
        cv::waitKey(33);
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the composite window (using some random test video off the web):

[image: Example Composite frame]

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, although I'm not sure why one can't rely on `vid.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT);` (mine returns 0 as well). Could you please modify your post with your version of OpenCV indicated somewhere? It could prove useful later.